# Why use Dependency Injection in this example?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

Consider the following code:

```
class CategoryController
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new CategoryModel();
    }
}
```

You will see that Controller depends on the Model.  I've heard that doing so is not desirable and Model should be injected instead.

I question why.  In my case, I build `CategoryModel` specifically for `CategoryController` and I don't see a problem leaving it like this inside the class.  I mean, I can't inject `SomeOtherModel` that's not compatible in there anyway... or can I?

Using Dependency Injection to instead inject it into the Controller seems like waste of code.

Hence, is there any reason to use DI here?

Comment: One reason for using DI is that you can't unit test CategoryController independently, because of the dependency on CategoryModel... you can't mock CategoryModel

Answer (score 1):

#### answer

Actually in that example, the big question is what is that for?! No methods just an object holder without any way to get it!?

Yea I know, it's just an example, but thats the problem, in that example you don't need DI, actually you not even need the class at all!

Has @Mark Baker said, without the DI/IoC you can't easily test, since it's tightly cupelled. If you take sometime to read about testing and for this case also [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/)

#### extra

> Using Dependency Injection to instead inject it into the Controller seems like waste of code.

When in cases where you don't have something that does the DI for you, it's easy to allow the objects to pass from constructor or make the default ones, in your example would be something like:
    use CategoryModelInterface;

```
class CategoryController
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct(CategoryModelInterface $categoty = null)
    {
        $this->model = $category
            ? $category
            : new CategoryModel();
    }
}
```

This way you don't lose much time, and when/if/maybe you'll do some testing, or change the model completely for another, it's actually possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need DI here. However [Mark Baker's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047911/why-use-dependency-injection-in-this-example#comment53917034_33047911) about testing is valid. But you can get around that by using a getter method for the model. That method can then be mocked in tests:

```
class CategoryController
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function getModel() {
        if(!$this->model) {
            $this->model = new CategoryModel();
        }
        return $this->model;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with that getter is that you have the CategoryModel hardcoded. How would you test it?

Comment: I would test it by mocking the getter and return what I need from that - which would be a mocked CategoryModel in this case.

Comment: Actually that I didn't knew it was possible.  Can you please provide a link to that documentation? I'm struggling in finding it.

Comment: What are you exactly searching for? A way how to mock the getter method?

Comment: Yeah. since if the class being tested is `CategoryController` (which is the one with the hardcoded `new`) how can you mock its method?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. Was occupied. I would simply mock the method even if it is the class under test. Why not?

Comment: I'm just not seeing how is that possible. But I will investigate! thanks! :D

Comment: @mloureiro: You could create a `setModel` method in CategoryController and inject your own `FakeCategoryModel()`, which you can use in testing.  You will not have to use facilities to mock `getModel()` method that way.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, that's also an option